# Get the column value that contains only one register in a table to an implicit cursor

Tags: sql, plsql, inner-join, database-cursor

I have these tables:

```
 table "articles_description" (a)
 code  desc
 1     article1
 2     article2
 3     article3
 
 
 table "articles_type" (b)
 code value
 1     inf
 1     def
 2     inf
 3     inf
```

And I need to get from the table b only the code value that get only and only one row with the 'inf' value (in the example I need to pass the code 2 and 3 to the cursor) to fetch values in an implicit cursor for a loop (next code is FOR reg IN c_cur LOOP ... END LOOP;).

This is the implicit cursor:

```
 cursor c_cur is 
 select a.*
 from articles_description a, 
      articles_type b
 where a.code = b.code
 and b.value = 'inf'; --(only need to get the article code that has 1 row with 'inf' value)
```

I have tried to build a function to return the article code, but doesn't work in this type cursor and the requirements forces to be built by this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select   "code"
from     b join a using("code") 
group by "code"
having   count(*) < 2 
and      max("value") = 'inf'
```

| code |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TJzRrj1F)

Comment: In case I have more than 2 columns in the table a, I need to put all columns in group clause?

Comment: @reymagnus depends what's in the column, but yes